# Adding a year in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
select current_date
```

Will return

```
Date
----
2014-10-16
```

so is there any function or way to get the same `day` and `month` with *next* year, I.e

```
next_year_date
----
2015-10-16
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select 
(current_date + interval  '1 year')::date next_year_date
```

Or

```
select 
date (now()::date + interval '1 year') next_year_date
```

---

[**Date/Time Functions and Operators**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-datetime.html)